# How to reinstall Java in R in order to make rJava loadable?

Tags: r, rjava, glmulti

I have been trying to download and use the package `glmulti`, but have found no success, since there the error `Error: package ‘rJava’ could not be loaded` is continually yielded.

After doing some googling, I found that the solution was to reinstall Java, so I downloaded it via https://java.com/en/download/mac_download.jsp and then restarted my computer. Sadly, the command `library(glmulti)` yields the same error as before.

I should note that, when I tried to check what version of Java I had installed using `java -version`, I got: `Error: object 'java' not found`. How should I remedy this?

Comment: Have you tried `R CMD javareconf`?

Comment: This will answer and solve your issue:
https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/200661617-Package-rJava-could-not-be-loaded

Comment: @Sagar sadly these posts are aimed for Windows, I am using a Mac OSX

Answer (score 1):

Now, there is lots of issues with Java, R and macOS. In general, it's not that easy. If you want to get rJava running in R 3.3, take a look here:

[R, Java, rJava and macOS adventures](http://www.owsiak.org/?p=3671)

If you use R 3.4, you will have little bit more struggle due to the fact that most recent R version uses Clang 4.0 :(. Take a look here:

[R 3.4, rJava, macOS and even more mess ;)](http://www.owsiak.org/?p=3718)

I am sorry to say that, but I think there is no easy way to get it running without too much effort :(

Comment: Gah, I was afraid of that. I read some other posts around the web that also referred to the difficulties on using Java in Mac OSX 10.12. I'll try and use a different approach then for my current problem.